# how to access combox in the tool bar with pywinauto

Tags: pywinauto

Here is the output of `print_control_identifiers()` for the current control.

there is no title for the `ComboBox` Control. How can I access the combox control ?

Control Identifiers:

```
Toolbar - 'toolStrip2'    (L0, T47, R1920, B74)
['Toolbar', 'toolStrip2Toolbar', 'toolStrip2']
child_window(title="toolStrip2", auto_id="demoToolStrip", control_type="ToolBar")
   |
   | ComboBox - ''    (L90, T49, R490, B72)
   | ['ComboBoxRitchie_22_158', 'ComboBox', 'demo:ComboBox', 'ComboBox']
   | child_window(auto_id="6491086", control_type="ComboBox")
   |    |
   |    | Static - ''    (L3, T3, R380, B20)
   |    | ['Static', 'Static0', 'Static1']
   |    |
   |    | Button - 'Open'    (L474, T50, R489, B71)
   |    | ['OpenButton', 'Button', 'Open']
   |    | child_window(title="Open", control_type="Button")
   |
   | Static - 'demo:'    (L0, T48, R89, B72)
   | ['Static2', 'demo:', 'demo:Static']
   | child_window(title="demo:", control_type="Text")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the names given in the list in the dump tree for the control if not the title, Along with that you can use autoid (provided it is not changing frequently).

`['ComboBoxRitchie_22_158', 'ComboBox', 'demo:ComboBox', 'ComboBox']`

For example =

`app.ComboBox.click_input()` - This will work if there is only one ComboBox, if there are more than one ComboBox then it will change for 2nd ComboBox it will be something `ComboBox2`